# Codeigniter Amazon SES SMTP Connect Error

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, codeigniter-3, amazon-ses

I want to send email using Amazon SES in Codeigniter, i have tried everything, i also tried the earlier questions asked on codeigniter too, but i am not able to find the solution for this.

```
public function add_applicants()
{
 $this->load->model('visa/India_model');
 $datan = $this->India_model->insertappdata();
 $appid = $datan[appid];

 $this->load->library('email');
 $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
 $config['charset'] = 'ISO-8859-1';
 $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
 $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";
 $config['smtp_user'] = "SMTP USER SES";
 $config['smtp_pass'] = "SMTP Password SES";
 $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
 $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
 $config['mailsender'] = "support@indiaevisaservice.com";
 $config['smtp_crypto']  = 'tls';

$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->print_debugger();
$this->email->from('support@verfiedemail.com', 'GYEV Experts');
$this->email->to('imthegrv@gmail.com', 'Test To');
$this->email->subject('Test');
$this->email->message('test');

if($this->email->send()):
       print_r($appid);
   else:
       print_r($this->email->print_debugger());
      endif;

}
```

i am getting error

SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Aha, i think one should answer first then make a downvote to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't follow the link provided in the error message, which provides tests that you can use to diagnose your problem.

These three lines are inconsistent:

```
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";
$config['smtp_port'] = "465";
$config['smtp_crypto']  = 'tls';
```

`tls` mode will not work on port 465. That should be `ssl`. Alternatively, change port to `587`, and it should be an integer, not a string. There's also no need for the `ssl://` prefix on your host; that just adds confusion. First step, change them to this:

```
$config['smtp_host'] = 'email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_crypto']  = 'ssl';
```

You may still have other issues (e.g. your ISP may block outbound SMTP connections), but there are many other tests listed in the guide that will help you diagnose that.

Comment: i have followed your instruction, but still i am having the same issue, i also verified that SMTP Connections are not getting blocked by My ISP.

Comment: Post the results of your tests in your question. We can't guess.